# Does individual array elements decay to pointer?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, addressof

I know that arrays decay to pointer. As a result, because it behaves like a pointer, it can essentially be passed to functions with arguments that require a memory address without the use of an ampersand. For instance:

```
char name[10];
scanf("%s", name);
```

is correct.

However, let's say if I want to fill in only the first element of 'name' array, why can't I write it as

```
scanf("%c", name[0]);
```

but must write it with the ampersand in front of 'name[0]'? Does this mean that individual array elements do not decay to pointers and do not hold their individual memory address as opposed to their entire array counterpart?

Comment: How can `name[0]` can decay to pointer if it returns the value of first element of array????...

Comment: Ah I have never thought of that array elements return values and not memory address and thus not a pointer as an explanation. Thanks!

Comment: @TruthOrDare Maybe you should take a look at [Array of Pointers](http://ideone.com/OgJtST)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Arrays** decay to pointer to the first element when passed as function argument, not **array element(s)**.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.3.2.1/ p3, Lvalues, arrays, and function designators, (*emphasis mine*)

> Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator, or the
>   unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that **has
>   type *‘‘array of type’’*** is converted to an expression with type *‘‘pointer to type’’* that points
>   to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue.

An array element is not of array *type*, the array variable is. In other words, an array name is not the same as a(ny) array element, after all.

So, individual array elements **do not** decay to *pointer-to-anything-at-all* even if passed as function arguments.

Comment: I'm just curious, does `Array` decay to Pointer to its first element or the `Array name` decay to pointer?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `char name[10]` can behave as `char* name` which is ok for `scanf` which **expects second argument to be a pointer** (address in memory). But when you write `name[0]` you are getting the value and not the pointer.

For example if `name` is `"Hello world"` then `name[0] == 'H'`. But `scanf` wants a pointer. So in order to get `name[0]`'s address you need to write `scanf("%c", &name[0])`.